# Calcular tempo de duração - Firebird 2.5

Tags: select, firebird, time

Possuo a seguinte tabela: 
[image: tabela]

Etapas: 0 = Separação, 1 = Embalagem, 2 = Conferência, 3 = Embarque

Status: 0 = Aguardando, 1 = Iniciado, 2 = Finalizado, 3 = Em pausa

E esta tabela faz parte desta tela:

[image: tela]

Por exemplo, analisando a imagem abaixo, notamos que a etapa de Separação esta aguardando a partir das 15h06min e finalizou as 16h16min. Sendo assim, o tempo de duração desta etapa foi de 1h10min:

[image: separacao]

.

Preciso calcular o tempo de duração de cada etapa independente do status, mas não sei como. (Ciente de que terei que criar uma view temporária para cada etapa)

É possível fazer isto? Caso sim, como?

Comment: Fazer a diferença entre o resultado das funções de agregação MAX e MIN sobre a data/hora e cláusula GROUP BY por etapa?

Comment: não faz diferença, consegui a solução para este problema.

Comment: Diferença, que eu mencionei acima, é a operação de subtração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver transformando hora das ocorrências em minutos :

```
  with vwEtapas as
(

select    a.idf_processoexp,
          a.etapa,
          a.status,
          b.IDF_IDENT ididentusu,
         sum(
              (CAST(SUBSTRING(a.horaoco FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) * 60)  +
              (CAST(SUBSTRING(a.horaoco FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
              )
           HorasEmMinutos

FROM       M3_OCOPROCEXP   A
inner join MTMG_USUA B on B.ID = A.IDF_USUARIO

group by a.idf_processoexp, a.status, a.etapa, b.IDF_IDENT
order by a.idf_processoexp, a.etapa, a.status

)


, vwEtapasClassifica as (

select wep2.idf_processoexp,
       wep2.ididentusu,
       /* Horas Separação */

       case when wep2.etapa = 0 then
            case  when wep2.status = 1 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasInicioSeparacao,

        case when wep2.etapa = 0 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasConcluidoSeparacao,

       case when wep2.etapa = 0 then
            case  when wep2.status = 4 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasPausaSeparacao,


       /* Horas Embalagem */

       case when wep2.etapa = 1 then
            case  when wep2.status = 1 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasInicioEmbalagem,

        case when wep2.etapa = 1 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasConcluidoEmbalagem,

       case when wep2.etapa = 1 then
            case  when wep2.status = 3 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasPausaEmbalagem,

       /* Horas Conferência */

       case when wep2.etapa = 2 then
            case  when wep2.status = 1 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasInicioConferencia,

       case when wep2.etapa = 2 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasConcluidoConferencia,

         case when wep2.etapa = 2 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end HorasPausaConferencia,

       /* Horas Embarque */

        case when wep2.etapa = 3 then
            case  when wep2.status = 1 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end  HorasInicioEmbarque,

        case when wep2.etapa = 3 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end  HorasConcluidoEmbarque,

        case when wep2.etapa = 3 then
            case  when wep2.status = 2 then
                       wep2.HorasEmMinutos
            else 0 end
       else 0 end  HorasPausaEmbarque

FROM    vwEtapas   wep2

)


, vwEtapasSUM as   (

select    wep3.idf_processoexp,
          wep3.ididentusu,
       sum(wep3.HorasInicioSeparacao)    HorasInicioSeparacao,

       sum(wep3.HorasConcluidoSeparacao) HorasConcluidoSeparacao,

       sum(wep3.HorasInicioEmbalagem)   HorasInicioEmbalagem,

       sum(wep3.HorasInicioConferencia) HorasInicioConferencia,

       sum(wep3.HorasInicioEmbarque)    HorasInicioEmbarque,

       sum(wep3.HorasConcluidoEmbalagem) HorasConcluidoEmbalagem,

       sum(wep3.HorasConcluidoConferencia) HorasConcluidoConferencia,

       sum(wep3.HorasConcluidoEmbarque) HorasConcluidoEmbarque,

       sum(wep3.HorasPausaSeparacao)    HorasPausaSeparacao,

       sum(wep3.HorasPausaEmbalagem) HorasPausaEmbalagem,

       sum(wep3.HorasPausaConferencia) HorasPausaConferencia,

       sum(wep3.HorasPausaEmbarque) HorasPausaEmbarque

FROM    vwEtapasClassifica   wep3

group by wep3.idf_processoexp, wep3.ididentusu

)

select
       doc.nrodocto,
       idusu.nome,
      (vwe.HorasConcluidoSeparacao - vwe.HorasInicioSeparacao - vwe.HorasPausaSeparacao) TempoSeparacao,
      (vwe.HorasConcluidoEmbalagem - vwe.HorasInicioEmbalagem - vwe.HorasPausaEmbalagem) TempoEmbalagem,
      (vwe.HorasConcluidoConferencia - vwe.HorasInicioConferencia - vwe.HorasPausaConferencia) TempoCoferencia,
      (vwe.HorasConcluidoEmbarque - vwe.HorasInicioEmbarque - vwe.HorasPausaEmbarque) TempoEmbarque

FROM        m3_procexpedi   d
inner join  m3_integraexp   ite   on ite.id = d.idf_integraexp
inner join  m3_integra      itg   on itg.id = ite.ida
inner join  m3_docto        doc   on doc.id = itg.idf_docto
inner join  vwEtapasSUM     vwe   on vwe.idf_processoexp = d.id
inner join MTMG_IDENT       idusu on idusu.ID = vwe.ididentusu
```